# how to execute Cockroach SQL via HAProxy and to ensure that the SQL query continues to execute even if primary node is down

Tags: haproxy, cockroachdb

I'm working on docker cockroachdb 3 node cluster with haproxy in my work space where i suppose to execute cockroach sql via HAProxy and have to ensure that the SQL query continues to execute even if primary node is down. But when the primary node comes down the load balancer haproxy unable to execute cockroach sql by picking the other working nodes.

here is my haproxy.cfg file

```
# Global settings
global
    daemon
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 50000
    timeout server 50000

frontend cockroach-sql
    bind *:26257
    mode tcp
    default_backend cockroach-sql-backend

backend cockroach-sql-backend
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option tcp-check
    tcp-check connect
    server cockroachdb-1 cockroachdb-1:26257 check inter 5000 fall 3 rise 2
    server cockroachdb-2 cockroachdb-2:26257 check inter 5000 fall 3 rise 2
    server cockroachdb-3 cockroachdb-3:26257 check inter 5000 fall 3 rise 2 backup

# Handle Haproxy stats for web browser
listen stats
    bind :8083
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats show-node
    stats hide-version
    stats refresh 30s
    stats auth haproxy:password
```

here the command used to execute cockroach sql from node1 container via haproxy:
docker exec -it cockroachdb-1 ./cockroach sql --certs-dir=certs --host=haproxy:26257

it works and i can see my test data of primary node via haproxy. when i killed the primary node, the load balancer haproxy should take the other working nodes but instead haproxy exists too.

any help will be appreciated, thanks..

Comment: Did you see any error messages from the 2 living nodes?

Comment: There're also some cockroach db documentation on how to start nodes with HAProxy: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v22.2/deploy-cockroachdb-on-premises-insecure

Comment: there is no error messages from the nodes

Comment: Try replacing the hostnames with the IP addresses of each node in your `haproxy.cfg` file.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the CockroachDB SQL shell in a way that it isn't intended. The shell is for interactive SQL queries, and doesn't handle statement level retries when the connection fails.

You should instead write an application with a CockroachDB compatible [driver](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v23.1/install-client-drivers.html) (most PostgreSQL drivers) that connects to the HAProxy host and has retry logic for the application's statements/transactions. For example, there's a Python example application that uses psycopg3 and has [transaction retries](https://github.com/cockroachdb/example-app-python-psycopg3/blob/main/example.py#L70). And I would also follow the HAProxy example in the docs link from RCX's comment above.